# angular2 material observable update UI refreshes

Tags: angular, angular-material, observable

This is a more general problem however in this case I have a list of todos (belonging to an observable) with checkboxes. When I update the state of checkbox the whole observable is refreshed and the UI updates, and in this case (if they are on) the checkboxes 'blink' from off to on.

Is there a way to avoid this?

My component is:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myTasksSub = MeteorObservable.subscribe('myTasks', this.username).subscribe(() => {
      MeteorObservable.autorun().subscribe(() => {
        this.tasks = Tasks.find();

        if (!this.tasks) return;
      });
    });
  }
```

and html:

```
<div class="card-outer" *ngFor="let task of tasks | async; let i = index">
    <div class="card-container">
        <div class='card-body'>
          <div *ngFor="let todo of task.todos | todosFilter:task.filterTodos" class="todo-wrapper">
            <mat-checkbox 
              [checked]="todo.done" 
              (change)="toggleTodo(task,todo)" 
              [(ngModel)]="todo.done">
            </mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: I would just hide checkboxes whose values change using CSS, and then set them back to visible once their values are set.

Comment: But then they will still 'blink' it will just be me doing it directly. Ideally I want them to stay on if they were on and off if they were off, i.e. not change unless it was the checkbox being updated...

Comment: I missunderstood the question, I though this change only happens when the page finishes loading. You can try disabling material 'select animation' if it's done using css (using :host::ng-deep). if it's done using js then it's probably impossible to change.

Comment: Can you just check if value of checkbox is the same as the new value and if it is, not change' it? How do you set the value of the checkbox? Are you using reactive forms. Do you iterate through all form controls or set value to the whole form group at once?

Comment: Can you provide the code you use for checking the boxes in the first place?

Comment: i've updated my original question with my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue. Made two observations:

1. Checkboxes don't blink in Safari
2. Most probable reason for that is using `[(ngModel)]` (two-way data binding)

In [this blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/blinking-checkboxes) I've provided the two options - with and without it. Code without `[(ngModel)]` doesn't blink in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing this, I fixed this issue by adding a `trackBy` function which returns the index:

```js
  public identifyFnBy(index: number): number {
    return index;
  }
```

```html
        <div class='item' *ngFor='let item of items$ | async; trackBy: identifyFnBy'>
      
        </div>
```